# Adobe after effect alternative, for creating effects

Tags: adobe, alternative

Is there any alternative for adobe after effects, on Linux that can create effects like these:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ay-9y5riqA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3tJIXKiOGY
I would prefer open source, but even commercial would be good if there is a Linux version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Blender](http://blender.org). It is capable of create all types of visual effects, and works better on Ubuntu than on Windows, in my opinion. It is hard to use at first, but it is just as powerful as the commercial software packages.

Comment: thanks i will try that i see that tars of steel  was made in it..